# How to achieve that exactly one of two foreign keys is NULL and the other one is not

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In my datatable I have a table B which entries *either* belong to a Table A1 *or* a table A2. Each A1 has exactly one B and so does A2. Up to now my model looks like this:

```
TABLE A1
ID ... PK
B  ... FK

TABLE A2
ID ... PK
B  ... FK

TABLE B
ID ... PK
A1 ... FK
A2 ... FK
```

But now a B could belong to an A1 *and* an A2, what I want to avoid. So in table B exactly one of the two foreign keys should ne NULL and the other one not. Is it possible to realize this in SQL?

I am using Oracle DB 11g.

Comment: yea, I had this kind of table recently.. you just need to make the cardinality of the relationships to be `0..1` for `A1 <-> B` and for `A2 <-> B` (this means A1 will have one B as much as 1 occurance, but B might be either having A1/A2 or not ) -

and actually you might wanna remove B as the foreign key in A1 and A2, it's making a cyclic relationship (not allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're just missing a `CHECK` constraint on `B`

```
ALTER TABLE b
  ADD CONSTRAINT chk_one_a 
           CHECK(    (a1 IS NULL or a2 IS NULL)         -- 1 is NULL
                 and (a1 IS NOT NULL or a2 IS NOT NULL) -- 1 is MOT NULL 
                );
```

Now, from a data model standpoint, it's a bit odd that you have relationships both from `B` to `A1` and `A2` and from `A1` and `A2` to `B`.  That sort of cycle generally isn't ideal.  It seems like you'd want to eliminate one of the two sets of relationships.

Comment: I do understand the check constraint, I guess, so now a B either belong to an A1 *or* an A2. But how to ensure that my A1 and A2 both have an B? That's not guaranteed only with this constraint, is it? That's the reason why I thought about the (not nullable) foreign keys in A1 and A2

Comment: @stg - Yes, you would declare the `b_id` column in both `a1` and `a2` as `NOT NULL`.  Again, it would seem problematic to intentionally design this sort of cycle-- whichever entity is the child ought to have a reference back to the parent, not vice versa.

Comment: I see the problem with this cycle. But is there another (better) way?

Comment: @stg - Generally, you'd remove one of the two sets of relationships.  It's hard to know without knowing what you're actually trying to model but I'd guess that you'd remove the `B` from both `a1` and `a2`.

Answer (score 0):

As both A tables already have a B.ID as a foreign key could you remove the A.ID's from the B table and force a check constraint on both A tables to ensure the B.ID isn't already in use by either table

This would allow for the 1 to 1 relationships you require and ensure that a B.ID in one table could not be used by the other